# Chrome extension to remove or redact names from any webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, redaction

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that removes names (from a list) from any webpage. I've managed to load the extension into chrome in developer mode 'load unpacked'. But I can't quite get it to remove pre-specified names from a webpage.

[These are the files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cDbt5_AIGnAEly4uGRUIbuVIydJMySFI?usp=sharing) I've used.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I'm doing this to try and remove names / bias from a job application process (blind recruitment).

Comment: Add the code inside the question and remove the link, see [MCVE](/help/mcve).